# Error in reading from the pipe

Tags: linux, pipe

I am getting unusual results while writing and reading from a pipe. The runtime error is **Program terminated by signal: 13**. I searched about this error and found that this error is due to there are no readers to read from pipe while i am reading from the pipe in the child process. Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 50
#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1

int main()
{
int pipe_fd[2];
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

char message[BUFFER_SIZE] = "Greetings";
char read_message[BUFFER_SIZE];

if( pipe(pipe_fd) == -1)
{
perror("Error in creating the pipe \n");
exit(-1);
}

if(pid==-1)
{
perror("Error in creating the child! \n");
exit(-1);
}

if(pid==0)          // Child process
{
close(pipe_fd[WRITE_END]);
read(pipe_fd[READ_END], read_message , BUFFER_SIZE);
printf("The message read by the child is: %s", read_message);
close(pipe_fd[READ_END]);
}
if(pid>0)           // Parent process
{

close(pipe_fd[READ_END]);   //Closing the read end of the pipe
write(pipe_fd[WRITE_END], message, BUFFER_SIZE);   // Writing to pipe on write_end
close(pipe_fd[WRITE_END]);
}



return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions how to solve this runtime error?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your error with `$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: For the record, your code prints `$ ./a.out 
The message read by the child is: ` with the above compiler.

Comment: My gcc version is gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609. In gcc, I am getting weird output like 
The message read by the child is:  . When I tested on https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/index.php  I got the runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your pipe before you fork a child process. Otherwise your processes aren't talking to the same pipe.

Thus move your pipe creation code above the fork() call as follows:

```
if( pipe(pipe_fd) == -1)
{
perror("Error in creating the pipe \n");
exit(-1);
}

pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

char message[BUFFER_SIZE] = "Greetings";
char read_message[BUFFER_SIZE];

if(pid==-1)
{
perror("Error in creating the child! \n");
exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: You can click the "accept answer checkmark" to show you are satisfied but don't feel pressured to if you are expecting/wanting other answers.